# Dual boot win7 after upgrading to win8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I'm quite happy with the upgrade to Windows 8, but there are a couple programs I'm going to need to use soon that will only work under Windows 7. I only need them temporarily, so I don't want to downgrade to Win7.

Can I just install Win7 on a separate partition like any other dual boot? Or am I going to run into issues with that?

Comment: From a license perspective, this wouldn't be possible, as the Windows 7 license is converted into Windows 8 license. I would imagine you would have issues activating the 7 installation.

Comment: Assuming I have a spare license lying around, how about then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Licensing issues aside, yes you can, it is better to have W7 installed first, then install W8, then you will have no boot loader issues to deal with, it will just work.

If you install W7 second like you want to do, then W8 will no longer boot, you will have to use EasyBCD 2.0 software in Windows 7 to add W8 to the bootloader, not easy for most.

Answer (score 3):

Is installing Windows 7 in a VM at all a viable solution for you? I recommend VirtualBox, although the built-in Hyper-V ought to work as well.

Comment: Running an Intel Q6600, and it looks like it's incompatible with Hyper-V. I can try VirtualBox however.